# R: lmer test the fixed effect by anova(Model) or anova(Model, model2)?

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme, psychology

I have read some tutorials about doing ANOVA to linear mixed model.
However, I've faced some problems with testing interaction, main effects, etc.
This is what I used to do:

#### Test interaction & main effect

##### way1: Model comparision-- anova(madel1, model2)

```
# testing interaction

> Red.Model = lmer(Y ~ A + B + (1|subject) + (1|FaceId), data= df, REML= FALSE)
> FullModel = lmer(Y ~ A * B + (1|subject) + (1|FaceId), data= df, REML= FALSE)
> anova(Model, Red.Model)

--- this is the sampled output---
          npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
Red.Model    6 5720.9 5749.9 -2854.4   5708.9                       
FullModel    7 5719.2 5753.0 -2852.6   5705.2 3.7037  1    0.05429 .

# testing main effect A

> Red.Model = lmer(Y ~ A + B + (1|subject) + (1|FaceId), data= df, REML= FALSE)
> FullModel = lmer(Y ~ B + (1|subject) + (1|FaceId), data= df, REML= FALSE)
> anova(FullModel,  Red.Model)

--- this is the sampled output---
          npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
Red.Model    5 5727.4 5751.5 -2858.7   5717.4                        
FullModel    6 5720.9 5749.9 -2854.4   5708.9 8.4744  1   0.003602 **
```

###### RESULTS:

1. AxB interaction not significant.
2. factor A: main effect significant.

However, if I do it this way:

##### way2: anova(model)

```
# anova() to see all effects
> FullModel = lmer(Y ~ A * B + (1|subject) + (1|FaceId), data= df, REML= FALSE)
> anova(FullModel)

--- this is the sampled output---
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
        Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value   Pr(>F)   
A     219.782 219.782     1 895.72  8.5499 0.003543 **
B       0.322   0.322     1 895.72  0.0125 0.910926   
A:B    95.405  95.405     1 895.72  3.7114 0.054358 . 
---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Is it OK to conclude the following?

1. AxB interaction not significant.
2. factor A: main effect significant.
3. factor B: main effect not significant.

If OK, so what's the point to do way1 ?

Cannot figure out the statistical difference... Plus, the *p-value* from the above methods didn't differ much.

WHY do many researchers use "way1" rather the "way2"?

THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: Perhaps https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/03/anova-%E2%80%93-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/ might help you here. Also try looking for "marginality" on this site.